# Get duplicate records from one table and put into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get duplicate records based on name from one table and archive them in another table.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.User_Archive (ID, Name, Update)
    SELECT ID, Count(*), Update
    FROM dbo.Properties
    GROUP BY ID, Name, Update
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

This doesn't work. There has to be a simple way of doing this.

Comment: I understand neither what you want to do, not why it doesn't work.  Can you provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Answer, `CTE` mostly used Duplicate removal process:

```
;WITH CTE(
    SELECT ID, NAME, Update,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID)RN
    FROM dbo.Properties
    GROUP BY ID, Name, Update
    )
INSERT INTO dbo.User_Archive
(ID, Name, Update)
SELECT ID, Name, Update 
FROM CTE WHERE RN>1
```

Comment: might be good practice to put Update in the order by clause of the row_number() call, so that the results are idempotent.If the update value is insignificant, then this can be ignored.

Comment: This worked excellently. I was also trying to use a CTE, but had the syntax wrong.  This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: You are welcome. If it fine then accept the answer. This may help someone..

Answer (score 0):

you are grouping by the wrong columns.

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.User_Archive (Name)
    SELECT Name
    FROM   dbo.Properties
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
```